# Prove a transformation (not necessarily linear) is one-to-one

Tags: linear-algebra

From Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces, Halmos, section 74.

Let $U$ be a (not necessarily linear) transformation that maps a finite-dimensional inner product space $\mathcal{V}$ to itself (so for every $x \in \mathcal{V}$, $Ux \in \mathcal{V}$ and for every $y \in \mathcal{V}$, there is some $x$ such that $y = Ux$). $U$ has the property $(Ux,Uy) = (x,y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathcal{V}$. Prove $U$ is one-to-one.

My attempt: For contradiction, assume there exists a $y$ such that $y=Uv=Uw$ and $v\neq w$. Then $(Uv,Uw) = (v,w)=(y,y)$.

I thought initially that that was a contradiction but it's not. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Well. If $(v,w)=(y,y)$ and during definition of $v$ and $w$ you had assumed $v\neq w$.....

Answer (score 2):

$$\langle v - w, v - w\rangle = \langle v, v\rangle - 2\langle v, w\rangle + \langle w, w\rangle = \langle y, y\rangle - 2\langle y, y\rangle + \langle y, y\rangle$$

Comment: $(v-w,v-w) = (v,v) -(w,v) -(v,w) +(w,w) = (v,v) - (v,w) - \overline{(v,w)} + (w,w)$ right?

Comment: Oh, it doesn't make a difference actually. Thanks! How did the proof come to you so quick?

Comment: Well, what I really wanted to do is say $(v - w, v - w) = (U(v - w), U(v - w)) = (Uv - Uw, Uv - Uw) = (y - y, y - y)$ but $U$'s not linear so I moved the subtraction outside of the inner product.